# How can I maintain MapInfo GRC file attributes in QGIS/GDAL?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to manage a classified MapInfo grid file in QGIS - I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with maintaining the attributes of the classified grid? 
QGIS seems to assign them just a number (Grid value 51, 52, 53 instead of site1234_sector1, site1234_sector3).

It does seem to recognize that the different attribute values exist, and lists them in the metadata, but I don't see any simple way to pull that table linking the new grid values to the old grid attributes.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Current system that works involves copying the attribute list out of the metadata tab and pasting it into excel. This works, but clearly isn't ideal.